# hastable contains value condition did not works

Tags: c#, hashtable

I've created a SNMP scanner and store the SNMP value in the hashtable something like this:

```
      SNMPObject[] s = new SNMPObject[4];
      s[0] = new SNMPObject("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0");            // name
      s[1] = new SNMPObject("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");            // desc
      s[2] = new SNMPObject("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0");            // location
      s[3] = new SNMPObject("1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.4.1.1");  // count

      SNMPAgent snmpAg = new SNMPAgent(newAddress, "public", "public");
      Hashtable ht = snmpAg.getValues(s);
```

I run the scan in thread behind process. and retrieve the hashtable value:

```
      if (InvokeRequired)
      {
         this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
         {
            //load the hashtable to datagridview

            //Check if location value is empty. 
            if (!ht.ContainsValue(3))              //check condition did not working.
            {
               //do Set SNMP command
            }
            else
            {
               //do some other operation 
            }

         }));
      }
```

Now I want the condition to check if the location does not contain value. I want to do the SET operation.
But the problem is that my if `(!ht.ContainsValue(3))` condition did not working.

Even if the `ht.ContainsValue(3)` contains value, it still do the set operation. Can some please advise?

Answer (score 2):

You should use ContainsKey, not ContainsValue.

You should also use a `Dictionary<,>` instead of a HashTable, if at all possible.  That class would not allow you to make this mistake unless your keys and values were of the same type (or the key type were implicitly convertible to the value type).

If the key is present, but the associated value is null, then you need

```
if (!ht.ContainsKey(3) || ht[3] == null)
```

If the value is a string rather than an instance of SNMPObject, then perhaps

```
if (!ht.ContainsKey(3) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ht[3] as string))
```

Comment: I dont think I should use ContainsKey because all of them have key. just I need to check if th e value is empty "" or not. I've try use ContainsKey, but the condition will always false even if there's no value. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Ren I see what you mean.  I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I've tried the first one. The conditions always false. and the second answer the condition always true. Not sure why. Btw, the value is string not SNMPObject.

Comment: @Ren Probably because the value is "", as you indicated in your comment.  The null check will return false because "" isn't null.  If you know that the object will always be a string, as it seems you do, then the direct cast `(string)ht[3]` would be better.

Comment: direct cast (string)ht[3] would be better ? you mean use your 2nd answer?

Comment: I mean `(string)ht[3]` is marginally more efficient than `ht[3] as string`, and it expresses your knowledge that ht[3] can't be something other than a string.  Still, a `Dictionary<int, string>` would be better than a HashTable, among other reasons because it would remove the need for the cast.